# "Opera:CrossNetworkWarning" What does it mean, why does it appear, and what are the dangers?

Tags: web-browser

I am using the following browser with javascript and cookies disabled:

Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.15

When I try to access Github just now, the following message appears on my Opera Browser:

Warning
https://github.com/

A page on your private intranet requests data from your computer. For security reasons, automatic access is blocked, but you may choose to continue.

- This page does not appear on other times that I've used Github.
- I am connected to the internet via local ISP on wifi over dedicated phone line
- I've configured my Opera to allow javascript execution and cookies only for Github, but not for any other site, including Google.
- I can access the page normally via my Sleipnir browser.

I know Opera is trying to stop me from doing something stupid.

- What does this page mean exactly?
- Why does this message appear now, and not on other times that I tried to access Github?
- Is my private data from my computer being accessed in some way?  If yes then how exactly is that done?

I like my browsing to be mean and lean, and I only want to use Sleipnir in emergencies.  Being unable to access Github via my normal browser is very inconvenient.